# Validate image size in browser

Tags: jquery, image, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check image size (ex. 1MB) before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673657/how-to-check-image-size-ex-1mb-before-uploading)

How i can validate (simplest way) the size of a image before upload (in modern browsers) to a server with jQuery?

Comment: Image size could mean different things, but the duplicate I posted reflects file size.

Comment: if it's for a cms & your users don't have much of a clue, i'd say let them do what they want & resize the images on the server; if it's a heavy traffic website and you want to save bandwith jquery file upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) allow for image resizing on client side

Comment: You can't check the dimensions without first uploading the file to a tmp dir and then using PHP on it. You could use AJAX to accomplish that.

Comment: @mikakun jQuery-File-Upload still has to upload the file to the server temporarily iirc. It then spits it back to the user for modification via AJAX.

Comment: @crush wrong from jqfupload github page "Preview images:
A preview of image files can be displayed before uploading with browsers supporting the required JS APIs."; OP asks specifically about modern browser (are you leaving in another time frame ?)

Comment: I honestly don't know how that is even possible considering the file path selected in a file input box is hidden from Javascript for security reasons.

Comment: John Koerner your right, i vote to close, tnx

Comment: @crush i don't how this work, i believe it's not taking the image from the file system but from the browser, "intercepting" the upload event; that's just a guess - anyway great plugin, so look at it & u'll find out

Comment: It's always been considered a security exploit for client-side Javascript to have access to client-side files, which is why classically, one had to upload the image to a temp directory, then feed it back to the browser via AJAX. It seems some new APIs have crept into Javascript that allow manipulation of files: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File Kind of scary to be honest - a client side Javascript could now potentially upload a users files without their knowledge...

Comment: @crush I hear your concerns about security.  The browser can only access local files through the File input, which uses the browser's native file chooser (which you can't style).  Further, the File object that the browser creates obscures the real file path from JS.  So the only way for JS to load a local file is if the user clicks a File HTML element.  Were there other exploits you were seeing?  Best.

Answer (score 0):

it's not the simplest way, but jqueryfileupload is in fact a great plugin (it does a ton more than giving info on files before they are uploaded)

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

so i'm putting an answer as it's a kind of an answer somehow

also, in my opinion bad idea to refuse anything to users, deal with their mess as much as possible, in the case of an image upload, you can do it; they'll enjoy that more than a "go to resize your image" (which most porbably they won't know how to do)